# Backbone: Adding a model to Collection and render a View

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-routing

I'm building a simple Backbone app where I mainly have a view with a list of books (book name + cover image) and another view where I want to add new books to the list.

When I use a sample data the view with the books renders properly, but when I try to add books to the list it doesn't work and I don't know which is the problem.

Here is the JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/swayziak/DRCXf/4/ and my code:

HTML:

```
   <section class="menu">
      <ul class="footer"> 
        <li><a href="">List of Books</a></li>
        <li><a href="#edit">Edit</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      </ul>
   </section>

   <section class="feed"></section> 

   <script id="bookTemplate" type="text/template">
       <img src="<%= image %>"/>
       <h2 class="bookTitle"><%= title %><h2>
   </script>

   <script id="aboutTemplate" type="text/template"> About </script>

   <script id="editTemplate" type="text/template">
       <form id="addBook" action="#">
           <label for="title">Book Title</label><input type="text" id="title">
           <label for="image">Image Link</label><input type="text"/ id="image">
           <button id="add-book">Button</button>                
       </form>
   </script>                

</div>
```

And the Backbone code:

```
app = {};
```

// Sample Data

```
var books = [
    {title:'Imperial Bedrooms', image:'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/e/e8/Imperial_bedrooms_cover.JPG/200px-Imperial_bedrooms_cover.JPG
    },

    {title:'Less than zero', 
    image:'http://d.gr-assets.com/books/1282271923l/9915.jpg' 
    },
```

];

//Router

```
app.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '' : 'home',
        'about' : 'about',
        'edit' : 'edit',
    },

    home: function () {
        if(!this.bookListView){
            this.bookListView = new app.BookListView(books);
        }else{
        this.bookListView.render();
        }
    },

    about: function () { 
        if (!this.aboutView) {
            this.aboutView = new app.AboutView();
        }
        $('.feed').html(this.aboutView.render().el);
    },

    edit: function () {
        if (!this.editView) {
            this.editView = new app.EditView();
        );
            $('.feed').html(this.editView.render().el);
    }

});
```

// Model

```
app.Book = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        title:'',
        image:'',       
    }
});
```

// Collection

```
app.BookList = Backbone.Collection.extend ({
    model: app.Book 
});
```

// Book View

```
app.BookView = Backbone.View.extend ({
    tagName: 'div',
    className: 'book',

    template: _.template( $( '#bookTemplate' ).html()),

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
   }
});
```

// List of Books View

```
app.BookListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.feed',

    initialize: function ( initialBooks ) {
        this.collection = new app.BookList (initialBooks);
        this.render();
        this.listenTo( this.collection, 'add', this.renderBook );
    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.empty();

        this.collection.each(function( item ){
            this.renderBook( item );
        }, this);
    },

    renderBook: function ( item ) {
         var bookview = new app.BookView ({
              model: item
    });            

    this.$el.append( bookview.render().el );
    } 
});
```

// Add books view

```
app.EditView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'div',
  className: 'edit',

  template: _.template( $( '#editTemplate' ).html()),

  events:{
     "click #add-book":"addBook"
  },

   addBook:function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var title = this.$el.find("#title").val();
        var image = this.$el.find("#image").val();
        var bookModel = new app.Book({title:"title",image:'image'});    
    },

  render: function () {
      this.$el.html(this.template());
      return this;
   }
});
```

// About View

```
app.AboutView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'div',
    className: 'about',

    template: _.template( $( '#aboutTemplate' ).html()),

    render: function () {
        this.$el.html(this.template());
        return this;
     }
});
```

});

```
var router = new app.Router();
Backbone.history.start();
```

I think the problem is related with the Home router, the app.BookListView and the app.EditView, but I'm not sure of that.

Any help is welcomed.

Thanks.

Comment: For starters, there is an errant ``});`` at line 142 of your jsfiddle code. The view seems to be rendering when I comment it out [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GWQE7/). If you have an additional problem please fix your code and clarify : )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this example..for simplicity's sake, define a global books collection.

`app.books = new app.BookList(books);`

Pass your books collection to editView & BookListView in your router:

```
home: function () {
  if(!this.bookListView) {
     this.bookListView = new app.BookListView({collection:app.books});
  } 
  else {
     this.bookListView.render();
   }
},
edit: function () {
  if (!this.editView)
    this.editView = new app.EditView({collection:app.books}); // your book collection
  $('.feed').html(this.editView.render().el);
}
```

In you editView you need to make a few changes to your `addBook` function:

```
app.EditView = Backbone.View.extend({
 // your other code above
   addBook:function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var title = this.$el.find("#title").val(); //could use: this.$('#title').val()
    var image = this.$el.find("#image").val();

    // remove quotes to pass variables
    var bookModel = new app.Book({title:title,image:image}); 

    // this.collection is app.books, your book collection.
    // this will trigger the add event in your BookListView.
    this.collection.add(bookModel);  
  },

});
```

In your `BookListView` make the following changes to the `initialize` function:

```
app.BookListView = Backbone.View.extend({    

initialize: function() {
    this.render();
    this.listenTo( this.collection, 'add', this.renderBook );
},
```

Here is a fiddle with the changes: http://jsfiddle.net/9R9zU/

Comment: Thanks! You saved my day. One more thing, how can I add the new models to the top of the list instead to the bottom?

Comment: You need to define a `comparator` function. You can read about that [here](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-comparator). If you have troubles implementing it, you should ask a separate question since it is a separate problem. If my answer solved your original problem, you should mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to check out the comparator function.