# Sorting Collections Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, backbone.js

I'm attempting to learn Backbone.js and have run into a bit of a wall when it comes to sorting.

My model is a song, and it has the attributes 'title', 'minutes', 'seconds', and 'order'.

Right now, I simply add each song to my View by adding them as list elements to an unordered list. My function looks like this:

```
$('#oList', this.el).append("<li id = 'song' > Song Name: " + song.get('title') + " Minutes: " + song.get('minutes') + " Seconds" + song.get('seconds') + "</li>");
```

They are also added to a collection before being appended.

I want to be able to sort based on title (alphabetically) and song length (numerically, based on the total of minutes and seconds).

Is there any easy way to do this? I've read about the sort() function in Backbone, as well as the comparator, but I'm still not seeing what I am supposed to be doing. Mainly, how will all my elements be added back into my View? When I want to sort by title, do I have to clear the  list in my HTML and somehow re-add each element?

Any direction is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define a comparator, Backbone uses Underscores sort and sortBy methods to keep your collection sorted as you add models. Comparator is an attribute set on the Collection that can either be a string (which will be the property name in your data used by sortBy - http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy) or a function.

Here is a basic example:

```
var Song = Backbone.Model.extend(),
    SongCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({ model: Song, comparator: 'length' }),
    songCollection, song1, song2, song3;

song1 = new Song({ name: 'song1', length: 120 });
song2 = new Song({ name: 'song2', length: 90 });
song3 = new Song({ name: 'song3', length: 100 });

songCollection = new SongCollection();
songCollection.add([song1, song2, song3]);
```

Now if you examine the songCollection you will see the models are ordered by length from shortest to longest (song2, song3, song1) even though that is not the order they were added to the collection.

Note, you don't need to make all the models first then add them all at once. The collection will automatically sort itself anytime you add a new model.

The collection will fire a 'sort' event whenever it re-sorts. You can listen for this event to know when to update/redraw your views.

Comment: Okay, this makes sense.

I've set my comparator to title, but my ordered list remains in the same order (that in which they were appended). What am I missing?

Comment: Is the collection sorted correctly? How does your view code render the data? If you want it to update you need to listen for the sort event and redraw the view. A quick google search got me these links that look like they may help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18001349/backbone-adding-a-model-to-collection-and-render-a-view

http://liquidmedia.org/blog/2011/02/backbone-js-part-3/

If you need more advice, please post your view code

Comment: Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3RGRv/ As you can see when you add songs, the view isn't sorted.

Comment: 1) change this.collection.bind('add'...) to this.collection.bind('sort', this.render);
2) add $('#oList').empty(); at the beginning of your render function. Basically if you want the list to update you have redraw it with the sorted collection. If you just append a new list item it will always be at the bottom. updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3RGRv/1/

Comment: Thanks so much @mcbex, that helps a lot. One more question if you happen to know: I want to be able to sort based on the input of a drop down menu. I'm listening for changes on it's value, but how would I go about setting the comparator to that value and re-rendering? Or should I be doing something else? My current attempt is: $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#sortBy').change(function()
      {
       this.collection.comparator = $('#sortBy').val();
       alert("This worked");
      });
}); where #sortBy is the select form, and it's not working.

Comment: Glad it helped :) - if you're satisfied with the answer, please upvote/accept since that is how we get credit. RE your issue with the input, if you want to change the comparator, you can't set it directly on the collection. Instead call collection.sortBy(yourNewComparator) and the collection will resort itself.

Comment: Done, thanks for your help! Where would I call this? calling collection.sort has firebug saying 'collection' is undefined. Same with this.collection.sort...

Answer (score 0):

Collection -> comparator, sort

View -> event 'sort' -> render the whole collection or just update el's position in the DOM (using new model index in the collection). It's up to you. First is simplier but second should be much faster in case you have a lot of data.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more (or provide a link) about the first method? As in define the comparator (comparator: 'title' ?) and then call the sort function? I only have a few lines of data.